# Is it possible to add a custom button to a TForm caption near the minimize, maximize, and close buttons at runtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for Windows Aero Glass and Compositing (DWM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822609/resources-for-windows-aero-glass-and-compositing-dwm)
>   [Insert button into window title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631276/insert-button-into-window-title-bar)

I am Using Delphi 2010.

I was wondering if there was a way to add a custom button to the left of the minimize, maximize, and close buttons. A button that has a onClick event assigned to it?

This would be used on both modal and non-modal forms.

Thanx!

Comment: Very hard to do well with Aero

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert button into window title bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631276/insert-button-into-window-title-bar) and [How can I put a custom button on the title bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789064/how-can-i-put-a-custom-button-on-the-title-bar) and [Non client painting on aero glass window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634743/non-client-painting-on-aero-glass-window). What research did you do prior to asking this question?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822609/resources-for-windows-aero-glass-and-compositing-dwm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For forms with aero disabled or when your system run in Windows XP you can use the [`TJvCaptionButton`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvCaptionButton) (part of the JVCL) component, otherwise you must draw the button in the non client area using the [DWM (Desktop Window Manager )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions. Try these articles for an example.

- [Setting up a custom title bar on Vista/Windows 7](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/)
- [Setting up a custom title bar – reprise](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/setting-up-a-custom-title-bar-reprise/)

Comment: I think maybe we need to improve the JvCaptionButton so it themes properly in Aero (using the DWM functions).

Comment: @WarrenP that is a great idea.